# Problema al subir imágenes tipo PNG al servidor

Tags: php

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando subir una imagen png al servidor y no me funciona, revisando las propiedades el objeto `$_FILES["imagen"]["name"]`, contiene correctamente el nombre de la imagen: "vehiculo1.png" , pero la propiedad `$_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]` está vacía y por eso no sube la imagen al servidor. Yo uso localmente el paquete wampserver 3.0 el cual incluye la versión de php 5.7. **¿Alguna idea de porque pasa esto?** Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Puedes colocar el código con el que intentas subir el archivo para ver posibles errores?

Comment: Revisa los permisos de la carpeta donde deseas subir las imágenes.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Estuve buscando en varios foros alguna pregunta similar y no encontré referencia a este problema. Cambie la imagen png y ya la subió. Conclusión: algún defecto tiene la primera imagen con la cual estaba trabajando